# Obrigar seleção no combo ng-required

Tags: html5, angularjs

Tenho um modal em que preciso obrigar que o usuário selecione uma opção do combo e também insira um valor no campo de input. Usei a diretiva ng-required e  para exibir a mensagem de erro mas mesmo assim ele não está obrigando, Alguma idéia:

Desde já obrigado.

// **** html do Combo ******

```
      <div class="modal-body">{{'application.outbound.outboundBatchControl.wantToSeparation'| translate}}</div>   
        <div class="form-group">
          <select ng-model="selectedLabelType"
            style="width: 500px"
            name="labelType"
            id="labelType"
            class="form-control"
            ng-options="labelType as labelType.label for labelType in labelType track by labelType.id"
            placeholder="{{'application.msg.labelSelect.labelType' | translate}}"
            ng-required="true">
            <span ng-class="error" ng-show="modalReprint.$error.required">Campo Combo é obrigatorio</span>              
            <option value="" >{{'application.msg.labelSelect.labelType' | translate}}</option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

// ********** html do Input ***********

```
      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="LabelTo" class="control-label" translate>Label To</label>
            <input ng-model="inputPriorityTo"
                   style="width: 500px"
                   id="priorityTo" 
                   name="priorityTo" 
                   type="text" 
                   class="form-control fontSizeItemReceiving" 
                   maxlength="20"
                   ng-required="controller.isRequired"/>
                   <span ng-class="error" ng-show="modalReprint.$error.required">Campo From é obrigatorio</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Como assim **ele não está obrigando** ??

Comment: Opa LeAndrade obrigado pelo retorno, se não seleciona nenhuma opção ou não insiro nenhum dado no input e pressione o botão para seguir o processo seguinte ele vai. Minha ideia e de exibir alguma msg impedindo que o processo fosse adiante se não fosse selecionada uma opção no combo ou digitar um valor no input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem alguns erros no seu código:

- Para validar campos com o **Angularjs** é necessário que os mesmos estejam dentro de um elemento **`form`** com um atributo **`name`** obrigatório
- Neste caso aí não faz-se obrigatório o uso da diretiva **ng-required**, pois apenas o atributo do **HTML5** **`required`** já é suficiente para o campo ser obrigatório
- A condição da diretiva **ng-show** primeiro deve conter o nome do form, depois o nome do campo (input, select, checkbox, etc...), seguido da validação que pode ser $pristine, $invalid, etc.. Pode ver a lista completa [aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Utilizei **$touched** para que quando o campo for tocado a validação aconteça junto com a **$invalid**, tbm coloquei a condição no botão **`salvar`**, para que enquanto o campo estiver **inválido** o botão permaneça `desabilitado`, forçando o usuário a preencher o campo. *Fiz apenas um exemplo para o `input`, aí é só você implementar o mesmo para o `select`*:

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <!-- Botão para acionar modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Abrir modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Título do modal</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form name="myForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="LabelTo" class="control-label" translate>PRIORIDADE</label>
              <input ng-model="priorityTo"
                id="_priorityTo" 
                name="priorityTo" 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control fontSizeItemReceiving" 
                maxlength="20"
                required>
              <span class="error" ng-if="myForm.priorityTo.$touched && myForm.priorityTo.$invalid">Campo PRIORIDADE é obrigatorio</span>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.priorityTo.$invalid">Salvar mudanças</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeiro LeAndrade, muito obrigado. Um abraço.

Comment: Legal man, sucesso aí!